# Homotopy groups of quotient of SU(n)

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups

Let $X$ be the quotient topological space obtained by identifying the matrices $A$ and $\overline{A}$ in the topological group $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ (here $\overline{A}$ denotes entry-wise complex conjugation). Are there any techniques for finding the second homotopy group of $X$? For example, is the quotient map $p:\mathrm{SU}(n) \rightarrow X$ a fibration?

Comment: The quotient cannot be a fibration: $X$ is clearly path-connected, but the fibers of $p$ can consist of one point or of two points and are thus not homotopy equivalent.

Comment: First do it for the complement of the subgroup of real (orthogonal) matrices. Then use MV sequence of SVK for higher homotopy groups.  That should get you close to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an answer to a related question, which might or might not be useful.  There is a map $q\colon SU(n)\to S^{2n-1}$, sending a matrix $A$ to its last column.  This induces a map $X\to Y$, where $Y$ is the conjugation-quotient of $S^{2n-1}$, so it is potentially interesting to understand the homotopy type of $Y$.  We can identify $\mathbb{C}^n$ with $U\oplus V$, where $U=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $V=i\mathbb{R}^n$, so the conjugation action is $(u,v)\mapsto(u,-v)$.  The sphere $S^{2n-1}=S(U\oplus V)$ can be identified with the join $S(U)*S(V)=S^{n-1}*S^{n-1}$, and this gives a homeomorphism $Y=S^{n-1}*\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$, and thus a homotopy pushout square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
S^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}P^{n-1} @>>> \mathbb{R}P^{n-1} \\
@VVV @VVV\\
 S^{n-1} @>>> Y.
\end{CD}
In general, suppose we have spaces $A$ and $B$ with nondegenerate basepoints $a_0$ and $b_0$.  Then in $A*B$ we have contractible subsets $A*\{b_0\}$ and $\{a_0\}*B$ whose intersection is the interval $\{a_0\}*\{b_0\}$, so the union of these two subsets is still contractible, so we can collapse it out without changing the homotopy type.  This gives $A*B\simeq\Sigma(A\wedge B)$.  By applying this to the case at hand, we get a homotopy equivalence $Y\simeq\Sigma^n\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$.  If $n=1$ we see that $Y$ is contractible (which is easy to see directly).  If $n=2$ then $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}=S^1$ and $Y\simeq S^3$.  If $n>2$ then the first nontrivial homotopy group of $Y$ is $\pi_{n+1}(Y)\simeq H_{n+1}(Y)\simeq \mathbb{Z}/2$.

If we let $X'$ be the conjugation-quotient for $SU(n-1)$, we have an evident sequence $X'\xrightarrow{j}X\xrightarrow{q}Y$.  However, one can check that $q^{-1}\{u\}$ is homeomorphic to $X'$ if $u$ is real and to $SU(n-1)$ if $u$ is not real.  This means that $q$ is not a fibre bundle projection, so it is not so easy to extract information about $X$ from information about $Y$.  It may be better to compare $X/SO(n)$ with $Y/S^{n-1}$ and then work back to $X$.  (This is related to Moishe Kohan's suggestion in the comments.)